# About "mysql result" resources

Tags: php, mysql

when I use `mysql_query`, does Mysql actually perform the query right away, or does it wait until I call `mysql_fetch_*()` ?

I mean if a the query is very very slow (for eg. the result has many records), which of these functions will run slow? :)

Comment: Interesting question. However, [please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained and the deprecation process has begun, see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql-connect). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli); [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I'm not, I just need to use these functions in a debug function I'm creating, which displays all kinds of info for the given variable, including resources.. And I was wondering if I should perform a mysql_fetch on a mysql resource, to display the results within that info

Comment: I would look up EXPLAIN (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to get better performance for the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said, `mysql_query` runs the query. So, if the query itself is slow (involves complex or non-optimized conditions, etc), then `mysql_query` call will take some time.

If the query is fast, but results in too many records, then something like `mysql_fetch_all` may take time as all the records will have to be copied into PHP memory.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP.net manual of [mysql_unbuffered_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_unbuffered_query),

> mysql_unbuffered_query() sends the SQL query query to MySQL **without automatically fetching and buffering the result rows as mysql_query() does**. This saves a considerable amount of memory with SQL queries that produce large result sets, and you can start working on the result set immediately after the first row has been retrieved as you don't have to wait until the complete SQL query has been performed. To use mysql_unbuffered_query() while multiple database connections are open, you must specify the optional parameter link_identifier to identify which connection you want to use.

So for a query that has large mysql result `mysql_query` will run slow. You should use `mysql_unbuffered_query` for this.

Lets see whats inside `mysql_query` in mysql extension.

`mysql_query` executes the query. If it has any rows to return (`SELECT`, `SHOW` etc statements) it fetches the result and stores it in `MYSQL_RES` C structure. Whether it fetches the result or not depends on whether it calls `mysql_use_result` or `mysql_store_result` C function. The later stores the entire result. From [mysql_use_result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-use-result.html) MySQL C API manual,

> mysql_use_result() initiates a result set retrieval but does not actually read the result set into the client like mysql_store_result() does. Instead, each row must be retrieved individually by making calls to mysql_fetch_row(). **This reads the result of a query directly from the server without storing it in a temporary table or local buffer, which is somewhat faster and uses much less memory than mysql_store_result()**.

So `mysql_store_result` reads entire result But `mysql_use_result` dont.

Now the [C code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c#L1560)  corresponding to  `mysql_query` is

```
php_mysql_do_query(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAM_PASSTHRU, MYSQL_STORE_RESULT);
```

Here `php_mysql_do_query` calls `php_mysql_do_query_general` and in `php_mysql_do_query_general` function [**PHP calls mysql_store_result**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysql/php_mysql.c#L1513)

```
    if(use_store == MYSQL_USE_RESULT) { //use_store = MYSQL_STORE_RESULT here
    mysql_result=mysql_use_result(mysql->conn);
} else {
    mysql_result=mysql_store_result(mysql->conn);
}
```

So **`mysql_query` runs the query right away and store the entire result set in memory**. So for large result set it might be slow.

Once `mysql_fetch_*` functions are called rows are starting to be fetched from PHP's inernal buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Result is fetched when you call `mysql_query`. `mysql_fetch_*` just returns the relevant part of the result object.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question, `mysql_query()` runs the query, and returns a resource that is used by `mysql_fetch_*()`. so mysql_query() will be the one that will run slow for a slow query.